# NullPointerException crashes android app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I keep on getting `NullPointerException` errors on my app whenever I launch the activity. It just seems strange because everything is declared.

Here's my activity:

```
package com.example.calendar;

import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.example.calendar.Appointment;


public class CreateAppointment extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText nameTextBox;
    EditText timeTextBox;
    EditText detailsTextBox;
    Button createButton;
    Date date = new Date();
    Appointment getNewID;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);

        createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apptSave);
        nameTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apptName);//Assign the global name box
        timeTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apptTime);//Assign the global time box
        detailsTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apptDetails);//Assign the global details box


        createButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.apptSave:

            String getNewDate = date.toString();
            String getNewTitle = nameTextBox.getText().toString();
            String getNewTime = timeTextBox.getText().toString();
            String getNewDetails = detailsTextBox.getText().toString();

            DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
            db.addAppointment(new Appointment(getNewID.getID(), getNewDate, getNewTitle, getNewTime, getNewDetails));
            finish();
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

and logcat gives me this:

```
03-20 11:24:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 11:24:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(706): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calendar/com.example.calendar.CreateAppointment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 11:24:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(706): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 11:24:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.example.calendar.CreateAppointment.<init>(CreateAppointment.java:25)
```

the line with the error is this:

```
String getNewTitle = nameTextBox.getText().toString();
```

Comment: `at com.example.calendar.CreateAppointment.<init>(CreateAppointment.java:25)` did you look at CreateAppointment.java line 25?

Comment: how this work ??
String getNewTitle = nameTextBox.getText().toString();
    String getNewTime = timeTextBox.getText().toString();
    String getNewDetails = detailsTextBox.getText().toString();

Comment: yes it's the line specified below the logcat stacktrace

Comment: I still don't get why people are turning all their elements in the UI into members of an `Activity`. That doesn't make sense. It doesn't even correlate with the assumptions that members of an object represent its inner state. Total misconception / misunderstanding in the Android development community.

Comment: all the members specified are the ones I need to retrieve information to store into a database. Is there any of them unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the value of edit-text before entering any value inside it. So you have to move this inside onCreate method.

```
 String getNewDate = date.toString();
    String getNewTitle = nameTextBox.getText().toString();
    String getNewTime = timeTextBox.getText().toString();
    String getNewDetails = detailsTextBox.getText().toString();
```

So your full code would look something like this,

```
public class CreateAppointment extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText nameTextBox;
    EditText timeTextBox;
    EditText detailsTextBox;
    Button createButton;
    Date date = new Date();
    Appointment getNewID;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);

        createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apptSave);
        nameTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apptName);//Assign the global name box
        timeTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apptTime);//Assign the global time box
        detailsTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apptDetails);//Assign the global details box

       String getNewDate = date.toString();
       String getNewTitle = nameTextBox.getText().toString();
       String getNewTime = timeTextBox.getText().toString();
       String getNewDetails = detailsTextBox.getText().toString();

        createButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.apptSave:
            DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
            db.addAppointment(new Appointment(getNewID.getID(), getNewDate, getNewTitle, getNewTime, getNewDetails));
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

or else you can also put this code in button's click event like,

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.apptSave:

       String getNewDate = date.toString();
       String getNewTitle = nameTextBox.getText().toString();
       String getNewTime = timeTextBox.getText().toString();
       String getNewDetails = detailsTextBox.getText().toString();

                DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
                db.addAppointment(new Appointment(getNewID.getID(), getNewDate, getNewTitle, getNewTime, getNewDetails));
                finish();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: gives me a NullPointerException again on the line:  db.addAppointment(new Appointment(getNewID.getID(), getNewDate, getNewTitle, getNewTime, getNewDetails));

Comment: It's Because the value you are getting is might be null.

Comment: How can it be null sice they're all Strings?

Comment: where you have used your string code, inside button's click event or inside onCreate method.

Comment: Can you put it in button's click event and then try?

Comment: yes. when i put them in the onCreate it doesnt compile and when i put them on the button listener it gives the nullpointer error

Comment: @jPratas, Can you edit your question with updated code.

Comment: I got it! I forgot to create an Appointment construvtor with four arguments. This was really helpful though. I'll mark it as correct. Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

move

```
String getNewDate = date.toString();      
String getNewTitle = nameTextBox.getText().toString();
String getNewTime = timeTextBox.getText().toString();
String getNewDetails = detailsTextBox.getText().toString();
```

inside `onCreate`, after  `findViewById`

Comment: when i do this, it doesn't let me compile because of an error: cannot beresolved into variable appears on the new Appointment line

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing EditText  before initializing it in onCreate() method. You need to move following lines in to onCreate() method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create);

    createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apptSave);
    nameTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apptName);//Assign the global name box
    timeTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apptTime);//Assign the global time box
    detailsTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.apptDetails);//Assign the global details box
    createButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    // move lines here 
    String getNewDate = date.toString();
    String getNewTitle = nameTextBox.getText().toString();
    String getNewTime = timeTextBox.getText().toString();
    String getNewDetails = detailsTextBox.getText().toString();
}
```